# How to use 'rsync' to copy ubuntu system to another disk?

Tags: data-recovery, rsync, uuid

I use LiveCD and `rsync -av` to copy ubuntu system to another disk(same machine).

What needs to be revised?

1. UUID in boot.cfg.
2. UUID in fstab.

Anything else?

Do I need to revise 'initramfs'?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want an identical copy of the harddrive? If so, use `dd`. Is the harddrive mounted?

Comment: dd also copies empty space so it may be slower and that will copy UUIDs. But rsync will not copy the grub in the MBR nor that partition table, so UUIDs will be different than install. You also have to change UUID on partitions if you use dd you want to still mount both drives. Or if using rsync you have to reinstall grub and edit fstab. if swap is an updated UUID, change /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume

Comment: Why not just install Ubuntu on that other drive? It should work as expected with everything as expected (correct UUIDs, etc.) because there's probably many other things to think of to make it boot properly!

Comment: Every time installing ubuntu, I need add many ppa and do some softs install and config. So boring.

Answer (score 0):

rsync -AVax /source /destination --exclude=lost+found

if you want to boot from it, then fix your fstab in the new root fs, chroot in and fix, or add it to the original system, grub. should be all that's required